# how to keep the size fixed of jumbotron and place carousel on it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="imp/slider/sg-bg1.jpg" alt="tech" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <img src="imp/slider/sg-bg2.jpg" alt="tech" class="img-responsive">
             </div>
            <div class="item">
            <img src="imp/slider/sg-bg3.jpg" alt="tech" class="img-responsive">
     </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i have used the following code but the jumbotron is not fixed in size and unable to make transition effects on jumbotron

Comment: Why does it need to remain a fixed size? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of your responsive website?

Comment: Seems to work fine. You do have an extra list item, though. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9qo9yh2p/